# Difference between in and ref readonly parameters

Tags: c#, ref, c#-12.0

What is the difference between `in` and `ref readonly` parameters?

I found both `in` and `ref readonly` parameters make the parameter readonly and it cannot be modified in the called method. Do they have a similar function?

Comment: It provides better warnings when the parameter value is captured: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-12.0/ref-readonly-parameters.md

Comment: The [section on the subject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#ref-readonly-parameters) in the "What's new in C# 12" article gives a few examples why  `ref readonly` might be preferable to `in`.

Answer (score 9):

Imagine you require a reference to a value instead of a value as an argument to a method, but the `struct` you want to pass is a `readonly struct`. You have three options as of right now to pass by reference:

1. The `ref` parameter: This is not an option for you, as you are passing a `readonly struct` which cannot be modified, but because you could technically modify a `ref` parameter, the compiler must generate a copy of the `readonly struct` to guarantee, that the `readonly struct` is not modified.
2. The `in` parameter: This one is inapplicable in your case, because while it avoids copying the entire `struct`, and prohibits modificiation, there is no guarantee, that your parameter will actually be passed by reference - you can omit the `in` keyword when passing the parameter, to pass it by value. This means, that if you need to have a reference for an unsafe method for example, this would not work. The reason for the in keyword, is not for a parameter to be passed by readonly reference, but to avoid allocation. This often means passing a parameter by reference, but is not required.
3. The `readonly ref` parameter solves the above posed issue:  It is guaranteed by a compiler warning, that the value must be passed by reference and there will not be a protection copy, because you cannot modify the parameter.

To conclude: Only the readonly `ref parameter` will work, if you need to have a reference to a `readonly struct`. The `in` parameter does not guarantee that the parameter is passed by reference, and the `ref` parameter allows for modification, what means that the compiler has to copy the object to ensure, that it is not modified.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference is on the caller's side. Assume you have a fairly large struct that you absolutely don't want to copy around:

```cs
unsafe struct Foo
{
    // alternatively imagine a lot of fields being in here
    public fixed int Bar[32];
}
```

If you declare a method with an `in` parameter like this:

```cs
public unsafe int SumOverFoo(in Foo foo)
{
    foo.Bar[0] = 42; // not allowed
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.Bar.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += foo.Bar[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Nothing will prevent you from (accidentally) calling the method like this:

```cs
Foo foo = default;
int sum = SumOverFoo(foo); // yikes, you just copied 128 bytes around for no reason
```

Changing the `foo` parameter to be `ref readonly` will generate compiler warnings that you should pass `foo` by reference (using `in` or `ref`).

```cs
public unsafe int SumOverFoo(ref readonly Foo foo)
{
    foo.Bar[0] = 42; // still not allowed
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.Bar.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += foo.Bar[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

```cs
Foo foo = default;
int sum = SumOverFoo(foo); // CS9192: Argument 1 should be passed With 'ref or 'in' keyword
```

`ref readonly` parameters were also introduced in a way to prevent breaking changes when migrating older APIs that were introduced before `in` parameters existed (and therefore used `ref`) to now accept readonly parameters. For example pre-.NET 8/C#12 `Volatile.Read(...)` required a ref parameter (although it does not need the write permission), meaning that it was impossible to read `readonly` fields using `Volatile.Read()`. They also couldn't just change it to `in`, because that would break existing code bases that use `Volatile.Read(ref _myField)`. Furthermore, potentially performing non-volatile, non-atomic reads after accidentally forgetting to use the `in` keyword and creating accidental copies when using `Volatile.Read()` would have been a very nasty source of bugs.

So updating these older APIs with .NET 8 to support a wider range of use cases was one of the reasons to introduce `ref readonly` parameters (as they work with being passed `in` *or* `ref`).

See [the C# language design specification on ref readonly parameters](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-12.0/ref-readonly-parameters.md) for more details.

Comment: "int sum = SumOverFoo(foo); // yikes, you just copied 128 bytes..." This only happens if you also have an overload without the "in" modifier, correct?

Answer (score 2):

The two existing answers are misleading about the behavior of `in`. They suggest that specifying `in` at the call site of a method with an `in` parameter results in different behavior than not specifying `in` at the call site. However, given this API:

```cs
public unsafe struct LargeStruct
{
    public fixed int Bar[32];
}

public void M(in LargeStruct largeStruct)
{
}
```

The following two call sites will produce identical code:

```cs
LargeStruct largeStruct = default;
M(largeStruct);
```

```cs
LargeStruct largeStruct = default;
M(in largeStruct);
```

[Compare the compiled code on SharpLab.](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0ASgK4B2wAllAKb4DCA9lAA4UA21ATgMpcBuFAMbUIAbnTo4AZmxkIYAGbVsEYJ2KDg2ADJhOAc2rc1G4OgDe6bNdwyFFAB7UAJtgrlsAIT0BtKQgBdcTQAXwkMGURsOmxLNBtbXAAWbAA5JAAKAEpYqwSbXQMjE01sNj1DY3VSgF5sZ2oFMGI2YGD8mwBZDPKiqtMs9psw+Js862lktIRs3NGOwsqSrV6l6q06hqaWtvH87vcyiuL1wb2RhL2fTupgAAsGZwBJFjYMm/vHl+Y2AHlmSgMUgQfCpBhPUhsdzufRZAJ7SZwFIHUg6Y79UqrE4DOYJEYhIA=)

Though, there is some sense in which specifying `in` at the call site can make a difference, which is that specifying `in` prevents passing rvalues as arguments.

An rvalue is basically anything that can go on the right-hand side of an assignment but not the left-hand side, such as a constant or return value of a method.

For example, this will compile:

```cs
M(default);
```

but this will not:

```cs
M(in default);
```

The actual difference between `in` and `ref readonly` is only about the compile-time warnings that will be produced at call sites. There is no difference in runtime behavior or even in compile-time errors, just compile-time warnings.

Others have linked to [the table in Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/ref-readonly-parameters#summary) that precisely details all the differences in compile-time warnings, but the main point is that `ref readonly` will cause compile-time warnings for rvalue arguments, whereas `in` will allow rvalue arguments without warnings.

To see why this makes `ref readonly` useful, take a look at one example of it in a .NET runtime API:

**Unsafe.IsNullRef<T>(ref readonly T source)**

According [to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.isnullref), this API "determines if a given managed pointer to a value of type `T` is a null reference." Note that the API does NOT check whether the argument *value* is `null`, just whether the argument `ref` is `null`. A sensible use of the API might look like:

```cs
public void DoUnsafeStuff(ref string[] stringArray)
{
    if (Unsafe.IsNullRef(ref stringArray))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stringArray));
    }

    ...
}
```

Now, consider if Microsoft had defined the parameter of `Unsafe.IsNullRef()` as `in` instead of `ref readonly`. That would have allowed this to compile without warning:

```cs
public void DoUnsafeStuff(ref string[] stringArray)
{
    if (Unsafe.IsNullRef(stringArray.FirstOrDefault()))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stringArray));
    }

    ...
}
```

That code doesn't make conceptual sense, though, because there is no programmer-visible `ref` location associated with that `stringArray.FirstOrDefault()` return value, so the result will always be false. If someone wrote that code, they have clearly made a mistake, possibly incorrectly believing that `Unsafe.IsNullRef()` will check whether the *value* passed to it is `null`, as opposed to the `ref` passed to it.

So, `ref readonly` is beneficial because it enables triggering a compile-time warning in a scenario like this where the developer has clearly made a mistake.